# What does code on demand imply

Tags: oop, rest

I heard that code on demand is one of drawbacks of Restful Services but i can't find an example  to explain what is "code on deman", how to use it and why we need it?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

From: ["The RESTful CookBook"](http://restcookbook.com/Basics/codeondemand/)

> Code-on-Demand (COD) is the only optional constraint in REST. It
>   allows clients to improve its flexibility because in fact it is the
>   server who decides how certain things will be done. For instance, with
>   Code-On-Demand, a client can download a javascript, java applet or
>   even a flash application in order to encrypt communication so servers
>   are not aware of any encryption routines / keys used in this process.
>
> However, using COD reduces visibility, which is why this constraint is
>   optional. Also, not every API needs this kind of flexibility.

Comment: I'm a REST API developer, I read it four times, and I still don't understand anything about it. :)